ML on Vienna Stock Exchange: Predicting hypes for the ATX index and conducting sentiment analysis on the top listed companies
Hello everyone and nice to meet you! :)
I am new to this forum...
I would like to practice on ML and create a model which predicts stock hypes for ATX index (Austrian Traded Index) and detects the top listed companies for 3 different short-time spans (6 months, 1 year, 2 years).
To predict hypes, the idea would be to use a certain positive return for a specific time span, e.g. 30% in half a year or at least 60% in a year.
Then I would like to detect the key stock listed companies of Vienna Stock Exchange that mostly drive ATX's upturns and downturns, e.g. check whether and how the 5 top listed companies change when considering two consecutive time spans (for example, 6 months and 1 year or 1 year and 2 years).
For this second part, I would use a sentiment analysis.
For detecting ATX hypes, I tried to build a random forest classifier based on ATX time series (day to day returns), but I am worried that the results may be inaccurate since daily returns are always random.
My questions are:
-Would you have any idea on how to predict hypes for ATX for a given time span (for example, 6 month, 1 year and 2 years) and not relying on day to day returns?
-Would you suggest any reliable source where I could find enough material to perform a sentiment analysis on the top listed companies at the Vienna Stock Exchange? I am not sure where to find enough and complete text content on the austrian stocks to perform the sentiment analysis.
I am looking forward to discussing these topics with you :)
Thanks a lot
BR
Jasmine

many more Q&A be found using a search: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=predict+stock+%5Bmachine-learning%5D
